# ampscript personalisation not working in emails

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, ampscript

We started sending our birthday emails this month however on March 11th, the ampscript

```
%%Last Name%%
```

suddenly didn't work and was displaying on the email. Isnt this supposed to be blank if null?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want your email to blow up if the attribute doesn't exist as a Profile Attribute or column in your sending Data Extension:

```
%%[/* Modify to view AMPScript <div style="display:none"> */

var @lastName
set @lastName = AttributeValue("Last Name")

/*</div>*/
]%%

<!-- some other HTML -->

%%=iif(not empty(@lastName), properCase(@lastName),"Partner")=%%
```

Comment: Hi @adamspriggs, Thanks! you are right. someone update our profile attributes so the ampscript was treated as text.

Comment: AttributeValue is one of my favorite AMPScript functions now thanks to @AdamSpriggs

Comment: @Gortonington, Yes it's mine too, thanks to Adam, of course!

Answer (score 2):

Also, if you have a space in your personalization string, you need to use square brackets:

```
%%[Last Name]%%
```

[AMPScript Language Elements](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/ampscript_langauge_elements/)